# HTML attributes "disabled" and "hidden"

Tags: jquery, html

Are there any attributes like `show` and `enabled` similar to `disabled` and `hidden` in HTML.

I have a scenario for making check boxes `disabled` and `hidden`

Example: I have 3 check boxes of the same group say JAN,FEB and MAR .
1. On click of JAN making FEB disabled and 
2. Onclick of JAN making MAR hidden.

Output for above example  please look at the below screenshot.

[image: disabled and hidden output]

Jquery script to make `hidden and disabled`

```
$("input:checkbox").change(function() {
            var t = $(this).parents("form:first");
            function ischecked(c) {
                var count = 0;
                if ($("input#f79uim").is(":checked")) {
                    count++;
                }
                if (count > 0) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if (ischecked("f79uim")) {
                if ("hidden" == "hidden") {
                    t.find("input#fsmafx").prop("hidden", !0);
                    t.find("input#fsmafx").parent().hide();
                }
                if ("hidden" == "disabled") {
                    t.find("input#fsmafx").prop("disabled", !0);
                    $("input#fsmafx").attr('c-disabled-by', 'f79uim');
                }
                if ("hidden" == "hidden") {
                    $("input#fsmafx").attr('c-hidden-by', 'f79uim');
                }
                if ($("select#fsmafx")) {
                    $("select#fsmafx").prop("disabled", !0);
                    $("select#fsmafx").attr('c-disabled-by', 'f79uim');
                }
            }
```

Similarly why not `show` and `enabled` attributes?

Comment: use radio button?

Comment: Specifically I wanted it for checkboxes

Comment: then add what you have tried so far

Comment: If show and enabled attributes exists I can write the script. If not exists what is the other way to achieve for enabling few checkboxes on click of one checkbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show the attribute use

```
 t.find("input#fsmafx").prop("hidden", 0);
 t.find("input#fsmafx").parent().show();
```

and to enable the attribute use

```
t.find("input#fsmafx").prop("disabled", 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write some jQuery on check remove attr 'disabled'. Can you please give some little example, what exactly you want?

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="class-chkbox"><input type="checkbox" class="chk-month" value="jan" > Jan</div><br><div class="class-chkbox"><input type="checkbox" class="chk-month" value="feb" /> Feb</div><br><div class="class-chkbox"><input type="checkbox" class="chk-month" value="mar" /> March</div><br>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.chk-month').change(function(){
        $check_month = $(this);
        if($check_month.is(':checked')){
            // do your disabled not show
            resetChk($check_month.val(), false);
        } else {
            // do you enabled and show
            resetChk($check_month.val(), true);
        }

    });

    function resetChk(value, isDisplay){
        $('.class-chkbox').each(function(i, val){
            $check_month = $(val).find('.chk-month');

            if($check_month.val() != value ){
                $check_month.prop('checked', false);
                $(val).css('display', isDisplay ? '' :'none');
                console.log($check_month.val());
            }

        });
    }
});
```

You may need to tune the UI and also figure out the way to get checked value. It will be easy if refer back my snapshot. Enjoy Coding!!